# Placeholders in eclipse 4

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

What is the proper way to have a placeholder with a wildcard in `e4`?

I am currently working on an old 3.x RCP using the compatibility layer. I used to have the views named like this:

- `com.projectname.GenericBrowser:Browser_Type_One`
- `com.projectname.GenericBrowser:Browser_Type_Two`
- `com.projectname.GenericBrowser:Browser_Type_Three`

and whenever there are multiple of each it becomes:

`com.projectname.GenericBrowser:Browser_Type_One_XX`

Where XX is a number.

I have changed the implementation and now it is:

- `com.projectname.Browser_Type_One`
- `com.projectname.Browser_Type_Two`
- `com.projectname.Browser_Type_Three`

and whenever there are multiple of each it becomes:

`com.projectname.Browser_Type_One:XX`

Where XX is a number. I thought that this would solve the issue. But no it didn't work. Using the E4 Spies I can see that every instance of any browser has a placeholder that specifically contains the `XX` number part which gets created automatically when `showView` is called.

I add the placeholder using

```
IFolderLayout.addPlaceholder("com.projectname.Design_Type_One:*");
```

This is done during the call of the `Perspective` `createInitialLayout` method.

I have also tried:

- `IFolderLayout.addPlaceholder("com.projectname.Design_Type_One:*");`
- `IFolderLayout.addPlaceholder("com.projectname.Design_Type_One*");`
- `IFolderLayout.addPlaceholder("com.projectname.Design_Type_One");`

All didn't work. I am aware of this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=441723. But I was hoping that removing the `GenericBrowser` part from my views names would help.